# How to get the count of array of images

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m parsing a json feed .using async image download I m downloading images (around 18 images) and storing it in UIImage.how to get the count of the images so that i can iterate in a loop.below is the code

```
- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage    *)image
{   UIImage *boom=image;
//download the image and storing it in UIImage

}
```

Comment: two down votes in two days..hate downvote..seriously wat z ur problem man(whoever it might be)..i m here cramming my head for a better answer and all u cud do is jst give a downvote..bravo man

Comment: I don't think this is a "hate downvote" - your question is not clear so it has been downvoted. You mention an array, but your code has no array in it. In fact, your code doesn't really appear to do anything.

Comment: if dats the case jst tell me de reason why u ve given a down vote..i d atleast change my answer for  better result...sorry for being rude i was little frustrated .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delegate callback you should be adding the processed element to an `NSMutableArray`. Something like this:

```
// MainViewController.h
...
{
  NSMutableArray *synced;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *synced;
```

And:

```
// MainViewController.m

@synthesize synced;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.synced = [NSMutableArray array];
}


- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage    *)image
{   
  [self.synced addObject:image];
  self.syncedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i images", [self.synced count]];
}
```